# mysql query tweaking fetch highest number in case of percentage or fixed type commission values are saved in one column

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a senario in which one column named commission is varchar , contain two types of values like this:

```
10.00%   type Percentage
5.00%    type Percentage
3.00%    type Percentage
£30.00   type fixed
£0.05    type fixed
£3.00    type fixed
```

Now I want to fetch them from database like this query ,

```
$sql5 = "SELECT  (commission+0) as comm , $cashback_table.* FROM $cashback_table where rg_store_id=$sanitized_store_id  ORDER BY comm DESC ";
     echo $sql5;
    $cashback_data = $wpdb->get_results($sql5);
```

There are three type of cases that commission need to be fetched, percentage type of values, fixed type of values or both in which I want highest value should come on top, like in case of above £30.00 is highest. it should come on top.

this query works good in case , if column has only percentage type values.

```
$sql5 = "SELECT  (commission+0) as comm , $cashback_table.* FROM $cashback_table where rg_store_id=$sanitized_store_id  ORDER BY comm DESC ";
     echo $sql5;
    $cashback_data = $wpdb->get_results($sql5);
```

I need your help to tweak my query that work in all three cases. help will be appreciated.

Thanks

if column has only percentage type values then it works in case of per

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: i am using mysql, php, in wordpress

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to sort two different vectors and then requiring the magnitude of the vector be the sorting factor

Do not use

```
ORDER BY comm
```

use the MySQL replace function

```
REPLACE(str, find_string, replace_with)
```

then

```
ORDER BY REPLACE(REPLACE(comm,"\%",NULL),"£",NULL) DESC
```

You may have to use

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(comm,"\%",""),"£","") DESC
```

if `NULL` is not recognized by MySQL.

In short, sort descending with the `comm` after removing the `£` and `%` symbols in the manner used by MySQL

Comment: SELECT (replace(replace(commission,"%",''),"£",'')+0) as comm From wp_cb_rg_cashback where rg_store_id=1984 ORDER BY comm DESC

Comment: £ sign does process in php file with this query. any help would be appreciated. 
SELECT ( replace(replace(commission, '%',''), '£','')+0 ) AS comm , wp_cb_rg_cashback.* FROM wp_cb_rg_cashback WHERE rg_store_id=$sanitized_store_id order by comm DESC